# How to restore bash terminal title if using 'set title' in vim?

Tags: vimrc, terminal

I recently got to know that useful info can be shown in title of bash terminal when editing files using vim. Adding below displays file name, path of the file being edited.

```
set title
```

But on exiting vim, the title is set to 'Thanks for flying vim'. I have different title set for each bash terminal and would like it to be restored once I close the vim?

Any way to change this behaviour of vim?

Before:
[image]

While editing a file in vim:
[image]

After:
[image]

Animation: see the title text
[image: Animation]

Comment: This is between Vim and your terminal, it has nothing to do with bash (on a side note: there is no such thing as a "bash terminal").  What is the output of `:echo has('X11')`?

Comment: I dont think this is possible with vim. May be possible with Shell scripting or commands.  I have asked a similar question earlier. 'Once the tile is changed to `Thanks for flying vim` , it can't be reset again. This is said to be for security reasons.  Refer `:help title `.

Comment: @lcd047 output is `0`.

Comment: @SibiCoder carpetSmokers answer works.

Comment: Well, this looks like Ubuntu, which is known to ship a crippled Vim.  But, if you say the solution posted by @Carpetsmoker, I suppose everybody's happy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `titleold` setting:

```
" Update term title but restore old title after leaving Vim
set title
set titleold=
```

From [`:help 'titleold'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27titleold%27):

> This option will be used for the window title when exiting Vim if the original title cannot be restored.  Only happens if 'title' is on or 'titlestring' is not empty.

Comment: Nope, the original title should be restored regardless of the value of `titleold`.  If it doesn't it's because Vim couldn't figure out the original title.  That could happen if Vim is compiled without `+X11`, or if `fs` or `ts` entries in `termcap` (or the equivalent in `terminfo`) are messed up.

Comment: As far as I know, original title can never be get again through vim. Can I tell more about it?

Comment: @SibiCoder Sure it can, it works fine here on X11.  But it needs a Vim version compiled with certain (combinations of) features.

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem is that Vim does not know how to read the old title, because termcap/info is missing the control sequence to do that. But we can supply it ourselves for terminal types we know it for. Xterm and screen use the same sequence, so this will fix both:

```
if has ("title")

    " if there is no &t_ts sequence, is the terminal type known?
    if &t_ts == "" && ( &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm" )
        " add the missing control sequence for xterm or screen 
        let &t_ts = "\e]2;"
    endif

    " enable setting the title only if vim can read the old one
    if &t_ts != ""
        set title
    endif

endif
```

Answer (score 3):

To set your bash terminal title to your short hostname when exiting vim, add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
execute "set titleold=".hostname()
```

At least on Arch, bash's default is the short hostname, so unless you have something else changing it sometimes, this will emulate restoring it.

All credit goes to a google search which found: https://gist.github.com/charlesthomas/9915977

Answer (score 2):

To supress vim changing the window title just disable the function:

```
"disable title modification
set notitle
```

Answer (score 2):

As of [8.1.0253](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0253), Vim will use the terminal's title stack to push/pop the title.  This is more robust than trying to query the title from X, but not all terminals may support this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
let &titleold="Terminal"
```

This line will change the title of the window after exiting vim. In my case, the title of the shell is just `"Terminal"`. You can read more here: [vim.fandom.com](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Show_a_useful_title_on_exit_in_an_xterm)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Good answers have more than just a link and a line of code; they explain how the answer solves the problem.